# Deduction of property of 1st derivative and 2 nd derivative if function satisfies some condition

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This particular question was asked to me by a junior and I was unable to solve it, in fact clueless about it. So, I am looking for help here.

> Question Let $f:[0,1]\to[0, 1]$ be any twice differentiable function satisfying $f(ax+(1-a) y) \leq af(x)+(1-a)f(y)$ for all $x, y$ belonging to $[0, 1]$ and a belonging to $[0, 1]$. Then for all $x$ belonging to $(0, 1)$  which $1$ of the following is true

A. $f'(x) \geq0 $.

B. $f''(x) \geq 0$.

C. $f'(x) \leq 0$.

D. $f'''(x) \leq 0$.

Can anyone please give some hints .

Comment: Many Readers will be familiar with the inequality you give as describing a *convex function*, or in the terms of Algebra II, a curve that is *concave up*.  The right answer is B, the second derivative should be nonnegative.  A proof of this fact is not entirely obvious, but if that is what you are looking for I can answer with some references.  One way to think about it is in terms of the Mean Value Thm., but applied twice to get at the second derivative.

Comment: That said, your Question requires more context to provide a good Answer.  Your mere mention that the problem "was asked to me by a junior" is ambiguous and gives no indication of what your background or interest in the problem might be.

Comment: @hardmath I am a undergraduate 3rd year and junior is in undergraduate 2nd year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=x^2-x$ has this property and rules out A and C. It also rules out D, either because $f'''$ is not guaranteed to exist, or in case of a typo for $f''$ as well.

To see that B is indeed trua for all such $f$: Assume $f''(x_0)<0$ and investigate the case of $x,y\approx x_0$,